# How to set Java DNS resolver cache TTL in Web Start application?

Tags: java, dns, java-web-start

I am able to tell the Java DNS resolver not to cache like this:

```
java.security.Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl", "0");
```

This works just fine when the program is run directly from the JRE, however, when run from Web Start, this setting seems to be ignored, and it caches forever. I don't get a SecurityException.

However, if I set the security manager to null, the setting will work in Web Start:

```
System.setSecurityManager(null);
```

Does anybody know a way to enable this property in Web Start without turning off the Security Manager? Also, if you can simply shed more light on what's going on, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Note, that it is necessary for enforcement of the same-origin policy that DNS mappings are pinned.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that `sun.net.InetAddressCachePolicy` is initialized only once in the static{} initializer taking into account the property you specify. Webstart loader obviously uses the class, hence it doesn't take your value.

However, since the property may not be initialized you can use `InetAddressCachePolicy.setIfNotSet(InetAddressCachePolicy.NEVER)`.

Alternatively there is a system property to add to the jnlp:
*< property name="com.sun.net.inetaddr.ttl" value="0" />*

If it is specified already by the webstart (have not tested) you can resort only on hacking via reflection `Field f= InetAddressCachePolicy.getDeclaredField("cachePolicy"); f.setAccessible(true); f.setInt(0);` *which may or may not work.*

Good luck and happy hacking!

Comment: I haven't tested this out yet, but since you've, at a minimum, given me more information, you get the bounty. Thank you.

Comment: @Marcus, the info should be valid for Java6 (or 7) since you're using webstart I assumed Java6.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running this with javaws? If you are, have you tried

```
javaws -J-Dnetworkaddress.cache.ttl=0 yourapp.jnlp
```

Comment: It's a security property, not a system one. Also, setting the property isn't the issue. It's being ignored. Thanks.